# Sans-serif font with both standalone and circled digits

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, sans-serif

I am looking for a sans-serif font, preferably a standard Microsoft one, that has digits 1-9 in standalone format (e.g. 1) and also in circled white/black variants (e.g. ① and ❶).

[Wingdings](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html) and [Windings 2](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html) both have white/black circled digits in sans-serif style but they do not offer standalone digits.

[image: circled digits in Wingdings]

In [Cambria Math](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/cambria_math/blockview.htm?block=enclosed_alphanumerics), I can produce all three variants but this is a serif font.

[image: standalone digits and circled white/black digits]

If there is no such standard Microsoft font, using the digits of Wingdings would be an acceptable workaround if these are available in another font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibri has them. To enter them, use the Character Map as [PowerPoint does not allow entering Unicode characters from the keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) and symbols inserted from using the Insert Symbol feature are rendered with Cambria Math.

[image]

If Calibri isn't enough, Noto Sans Symbols has them and is free. It's an incredibly useful font family and is worth installing on any PC, you never know when you might need a glyph from it.

Comment: [Noto Sans Symbols](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+SC?preview.text=1%20%E2%91%A0%20%20%E2%9D%B6&preview.text_type=custom&query=noto+sans+s) is a great tip, thanks. I tried multiple ways to get sans-serif circled digits using Calibri: copied Unicode characters from the web+paste unformatted and used insert symbol – but they were always rendered with Cambria Math.

Comment: Try copying them out of the character set using Character Map.

Comment: That was the trick indeed. Many thanks!